# Facebook Like Button post on feed dialog disappears

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-like

I'm having a problem with a facebook like button.

The problem is as follows:

When the user clicks the like button, a post-on-the-wall dialog appears (called with edge.create) but in just half a second, the dialog disappears.

Another thing is when you usually click a fb like button, your like is instantly processed, no problems here, but in my page, when you click the like button, the dialog windows appears, after a moment disapperas, and the text on the like button changes to "Confirm",
and only after pressing "Confirm", the like is processed.

(I am using the javascript api)

The problem should be obvious, but again - why does the dialog window disappear, and why does the like have to be "confirmed" ?

I've been banging my head with this problem for a few days and I really can't take it anymore, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using an app id for the include code? the confirm stuff is sort of a spam protection, and should disappear if you use an app > see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
it could also solve the problem with the disappearing window, but i am not sure...

Comment: yes, I'm using an app id, however I have not made nay configurations to the app, I have only craeted it so I can use the app id code.

Answer (score 0):

The confirm button usually shows up when a new like button is getting many clicks in a short time period to help battle "like-jacking". This is not a coding error, rather a facebook controlled function.

Comment: I see, but what about the dialog button disappearing. Any idea what's causing this?